# Packing three squares into an equilateral triangle

Tags: triangles, packing-problem

I am trying to pack 3 equal, largest possible sized squares into an equilateral triangle.

Comment: I wish you luck! (If you decide you'd like some help with that, let us know what you've tried, where you're stuck, and other details like that.)

Answer (score 3):

Erich Friedman, a professor in Stetson University got the solution to this as posted in his [website](https://erich-friedman.github.io/packing/squintri/).

His solution gives the way to pack tree unit squares in the smallest possible equilateral triangle of side $s$.

[image: Friedman's solution]

The formula for $s$ is easily verified using elementary trigonometry. Why this one is the most optimal configuration I do not know...

Reformulated for our problem, given an equilateral triangle of side $s$, the side $a$ of the biggest 3 equal squares that fit inside is

\begin{equation}
a=\frac{s}{\frac{3}{2}+\sqrt{3}}
\end{equation}

Comment: Note, that the web-page says 'smallest known' triangles, so it's most likely not optimal solution